# Get image from root subfolder

Tags: javascript, html, css

My background images in coffeeShop.php is not showing. My header in coffeeShop.php was not showing either, which I solved like this:

```
[![<?php include $_SERVER\['DOCUMENT_ROOT'\] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>][1]][1]
```

So I thought that I could solve the background image problem like this, but that is not working either:

```
{image : '../images/background/bg2.jpg'}
```

Does anybody have an idea what I have to do here?

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: what about `{image : '/images/background/bg2.jpg'}`? If the image shows what is truly the root of your website, that will get the image, assuming a lot, since I have no idea how this "supersized" thing works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That did not work either:-/